# Install APK in the Emulator using ADB in CentOS

Tags: android, installation, centos, apk, adb

I am new to CentOS and I want to install an APK in the emulator using ADB.
Using terminal, I used this syntax:

```
adb install <nameofapk>.apk
```

That command gave me this error :

```
Whoops: didn't find expected signature
read_central_directory_entry failed
file '<nameofapk.>.apk' is not a valid zip file
rm failed for /data/local/tmp/<nameofapk>.apk, No such file or directory
```

What do i need to do to get rid of that error message and be able to successfully install the APK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your APK file is invalid or corrupted, that's why it can't be installed. Try

```
unzip -t <nameofapk>.apk
```

to see if there's something wrong with your file.

Comment: Archive : JotatextEditor.apk
error [JotatextEditor.apk]:  missing 470 bytes in zipfile
(attempting to process anyway)
error [JotaTextEditor.apk] : start of central directory not found;
zipfile corrupt
(please check that you have transferred or created the zipfile in the appropriate BINARY mode and that you have compiled UnZip properly)  -- That's the message the unzip command gave me. It says here that the file is corrupted, but this is the same APK i used when I was still using windows OS. do I need to download a different    APK when Im using CentOS?

Comment: Looks like your apk got corrupted somehow. Hard disks are not infallible. You'll probably need to download it again.

Comment: yes thank you! I tried downloading the files again. and it was installed successfully! Thank you! :D